# How to map using constants in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to map an array of custom values using a constant that's already defined. I'm running into some problems.

This works perfectly:

```
Car.where(brand: car_brands.map(&:Car_honda))
```

Although I have all the car brands already defined in my file, so I would prefer to use the constants over rewriting the names. For example:

```
HONDA = "Car_honda"
```

When I try and map this constant to the array it doesn't seem to work properly:

```
Car.where(brand: car_brands.map(&:HONDA))
```

I tried to use a block with `map`, but I still got the same result:

```
Car.where(brand: car_brands.map {|c| c.HONDA}))
```

Are we able to use constants with `map`?

Comment: What is `car_brands`?

Comment: &:HONDA should be a column name in your example. So with &:something you map column name which I think in your case would be car_honda, really

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: `&:HONDA` or `c.HONDA` would work if `HONDA` is a method, but we don't name methods with a starting capital letter. `honda` would be appropriate. `&:Car_honda` would not be appropriate either, for the same reason. As a result, it looks like you don't understand how we define variables, methods and constants in Ruby.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you probably shouldn't have car brands defined as constants. Adding or removing brands should not involve changing your code. `Brand` should be a model, which maps to a table called `brands`.

Comment: Building on Tin Man's comment - go read a basic tutorial on Ruby and perhaps pick up a friendly book. There is most definitely a saner way to do what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Using a constant like `HONDA` is really broken design. `:honda` as a canonical representation of that brand is better. `BRANDS = [ :honda ]` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `send`:

```
Car.where(brand: car_brands.map { |c| c.send(HONDA) })
```

Comment: Do you think there is method `HONDA` defined?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `HONDA` is the constant that returns the string `Car_honda`, which does have a corresponding method. Also - *`public_send` is safer.

Comment: No. `c.send(HONDA)` calls method named `Car_honda` (value of `HONDA` constant): `HONDA = "Car_honda"; class Car; def Car_honda; puts 'Honda' end end; Car.new.send(HONDA)`

Comment: This will only work if `HONDA` is defined in the current scope, which I doubt.

Comment: Why are we guessing where the constant is defined? Looks like this question has turned everyone into a maniac.

Comment: @Inpego: ah, right, my bad. Still, this is terrible design. :)

Comment: The problem is, the OP doesn't show whether `"Car_honda"` is a method that was previously defined, or if it's only a String. If it's a method then `send` would help. If it's only a string with no method for Ruby to call then it won't work. The OP's question isn't well defined and doesn't tell us enough about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you're going with this, or precisely where you're coming from, but here's an example that follows Rails conventions:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
end
```

Then you can find all cars associated with the "Honda" brand:

```
Brand.find_by(name: 'Honda').cars
```

Or find all cars matching one or more arbitrary brand names using a `JOIN` operation:

```
Car.joins(:brand).where(brand: { name: %w[ Honda Ford ] })
```

If you go with the flow in Rails things are a lot easier.

Comment: Though it doesn't answer the question specifically, this is the cleanest and most efficient answer.. and definitely the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

> Are you able to use constants with map?

Nope. Not like this, anyhow.

> `car_brands.map { |c| c.HONDA }`

This means, for every thing in `car_brands` call **method** `HONDA` on it and return results of the invocations. So, unless you have method `HONDA` defined (which you absolutely shouldn't), this has no chance to work.

Comment: Car.where(car_brands: "HONDA").map(&:id) gives you the ids of the cars where the brand is HONDA

Comment: A sorry, it is not for sure. !!! ;-) This would only work if you have a column car_brands that has the value "HONDA". Thanks! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Constants are defined on the class, not on the object. You can invoke them through `.class`.

```
:005 > Integer.const_set('ABC', 1)
 => 1
:006 > Integer::ABC
 => 1
:007 > [1,2,3].map {|i| i.class::ABC}
 => [1, 1, 1]
```

This will not work for your use case unless `car_brands` contains an array of different `Car` classes.

Comment: You really don't want to make it a habit of spiking in arbitrary constants on core Ruby classes with `const_set`.

Comment: @tadman: I figured defining my own class for illustration would be overkill in this case =P. And yes, this would be a bad idea for an actual project.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you probably don't want to things this way. Perhaps it's the way your example is worded, but the only way it makes sense, as I'm reading it, is if `Car_brands` is an array of classes. And if that's the case, if doesn't make sense to have a constant called `HONDA`. If anything, you would have a constant called `BRAND` that might equal "Honda" for a given class. I strongly recommend you rethink your data structures before moving forward.

All that said, you can use `const_get` to access constants using map. e.g.

```
class CarBrand1
  BRAND = 'Honda'
end

class CarBrand2
  BRAND = 'Toyota'
end

car_brands = [CarBrand1, CarBrand2]

car_brands.map{|car_brand| car_brand.const_get("BRAND")}
car_brands.map{|car_brand| car_brand::BRAND} # Alternatively
# => ["Honda", "Toyota"]
```

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should. This violates a lot of object-oriented design principles.

Comment: I very much agree. This is just how one might do it if one were set on using constants. This isn't the best way of doing things, but it's how you might do it if you were set on it. It's hard to say what the correct way of handling this is without seeing more of the app.